# is there a Flask equivalent to MeteorJS Session functionality?

Tags: python, session, meteor, flask

I'm new to Python and have recently been trying to build a Python (Flask) web app. In the past I have made an app with the MeteorJS framework and found the 'Session.set...' and 'Session.get...' functionality really useful. I want each user to be able to set an 'active project' and then see a subset of information that project_id field match the 'active project'. I achieved this in Meteor though can't seem to find an obvious alternative in Flask. 
Does anyone have suggestions of what I could use to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flask already has a `session` functionality built-in.

Documentation: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.session

Example:

```
@app.route('/')
def hello():
     session['name'] = 'Foo'
     return Bar

@app.route('/name/')
def name():
    name = session.get('name')
    return name
```